# Filter Listview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this "attached property" and need to be generic. In this example, to work properly, I need to cast a variable of type "Employee". is possible to create something more generic, always from a "attached property"
Something more generic, rather than casting a "Employee", converted into string and use it for any listview

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterSourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FilterSource", typeof (TextBox), typeof (ListViewExtension),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnTextBoxSet));

public static TextBox GetFilterSource(DependencyObject dObj)
{
    return (TextBox)dObj.GetValue(FilterSourceProperty);
}

public static void SetFilterSource(DependencyObject dObj, TextBox value)
{
    dObj.SetValue(FilterSourceProperty, value);
}

private static void OnTextBoxSet(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = dObj as ListView;
    var textBox = e.NewValue as TextBox;

    if ((listView != null) && (textBox != null))
    {
        textBox.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs tcea)
        {
            var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
            if (view == null) return;
            view.Filter += item =>
            {
                var textFilter = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
                var itemPl = (Employee)item;
                return itemPl.UserName.Contains(textFilter);
            };
        };
    }
}
```

In .xaml

```
<ListView ...>
...
...
tools:ListViewExtension.FilterSource="{Binding ElementName=txtFilter}"
...
...
</ListView
```

>

Comment: use MVVM and filter in your viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not require the use of `TextBox` in `OnTextBoxSet`.

Try it :

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterSourceProperty =
  DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FilterSource", typeof(string), typeof(Extentions),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnTextBoxSet));

    public static string GetFilterSource(DependencyObject dObj)
    {
        return (string)dObj.GetValue(FilterSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetFilterSource(DependencyObject dObj, string value)
    {
        dObj.SetValue(FilterSourceProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnTextBoxSet(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = dObj as ListView;
        var text = e.NewValue as string;

        if ((listView == null) || (text == null)) return;

        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
        if (view == null) return;
        view.Filter += item =>
        {
            var itemPl = (Employee) item;
            return itemPl.UserName.Contains(text);
        };
    }
```

In Xaml :(set Path of Element)

```
<ListView tools:ListViewExtension.FilterSource="{Binding ElementName=txtFilter,Path=Text,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**EDITED :**

```
private static void OnTextBoxSet(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = dObj as ListView;
        var text = e.NewValue as string;

        if ((listView == null) || (text == null)) return;

        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
        if (view == null) return;
        view.Filter += item =>
        {
            var type = item.GetType();
            if (type == typeof(Employee))
            {
                var itemPl = (Employee)item;
                return itemPl.UserName.Contains(text);
            }
            if (type == typeof(Person))
            {
                var itemPl = (Person)item;
                return itemPl.Name.Contains(text);
            }
            //and more types .............. 
            return false;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but 2 problems:
1) The code does not work, does not filter the results when I type in the textbox, somewhere must be the **"textBox.TextChanged"** event
2) It's not what I asked. I need to avoid this **"var itemPl = (Employee) item;"** I do not want to cast implicitly to "Employee" I want to be generic and can use it with any class.

Comment: @avechuche,now underestand your problem,please wait for resolve it.

Comment: @avechuche,please test EDITED code of top,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You can select the first item after applying the filter? something like **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = "True".**

Comment: You can use this method : `var item = ListView.Items.GetItemAt(0);`
           Test :>  `MessageBox.Show((item as Employee).UserName);`